# How to remove Add To Compare links in magento 2.2.0?

Tags: magento2.2.0

I want to remove 'Add To compare' links all over the website. The Add To Compare  module is irrelevant for me. I am using Magento 2.2.0 version.[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can remove it by adding this line in your catalog_category_view.xml:

```
<referenceBlock name="category.product.addto.compare" remove="true" />
```

Comment: This is the right answer for removing the "Add to compare" link from the products in category page.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please **catalog.compare.link** in your default.xml find below path.

app\design\frontend\Magento\theme\Magento_Theme\layout

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it by adding a **default.xml** file to your theme in: /Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the 'Add to compare' link from your product details page, you can add the foll lines to the catalog_product_view.xml file you place in:

> app/design/frontend/(Vendor)/(themename)/Magento_Catalog/layout

XML code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

This way you can keep your settings apart from each other, so the removal will be set in de file it belongs to.

Answer (score -1):

Please add catalog.compare.link in your default.xml find below path - >

> app\design\frontend\Magento\theme\Magento_Theme\layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
               <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>
               <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
enter code here
        </body>
    </page>
```

Answer (score -1):

Connect via SSH and run the following commands in the root folder:

Step 1: php bin/magento module:enable Mage_DisableCompare

Step 1: php bin/magento setup:upgrade